# I have a table with three column ID, PARTYID, PARTYTYPE, I need to update all PARTYTYPE 'A' to 'B' for specific PARTYID

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table with three column ID, PARTYID, PARTYTYPE, I need to update all PARTYTYPE 'A' to 'B' for specific PARTYID.
There will be 2 case

- if PARTYID have only one PARTYTYPE as 'A' then i need to update it to 'B'
- if PARTYID have both PARTYTYPE 'A' and 'B' then i need to delete 'A'

For example

| ID | PARTYID | PARTYTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 1 | B |
| 3 | 1 | C |
| 4 | 2 | A |
| 5 | 2 | B |
| 6 | 3 | A |

Expected Result

| ID | PARTYID | PARTYTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | B |
| 3 | 1 | C |
| 5 | 2 | B |
| 6 | 3 | B |

Comment: You can't do this with a single DML query, because update is something different than delete.

Comment: With two query its also fine, for delete i am not able to extract ID as i don't have any approach how to compare same PARTYID with two different value of PARTYTYPE

Comment: C rows are not relevant, right? If there is only an A entry and a C entry for an ID, then this is considered A without B, and the A must get updated to B. Correct?

Comment: Yes if there is A and C then it should be updated to B and C, and partytype can have number of value i just need to update A to B because i am removing partytype A from table and if there is a entry A and B then i need to delete A as partytype B already exists

Comment: As a rule the `mysql` and `tsql` tags are incompatible (as shown in their descriptions). Do you really need a solution that works in both?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to run 2 query:

UPDATE table1 SET `PARTYTYPE` = "B" WHERE `PARTYTYPE` = "A"

DELETE FROM `table1` WHERE ID IN (SELECT `ID` FROM (SELECT * FROM table1) as tab GROUP BY `PARTYID`, `PARTYTYPE` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

Comment: Good day @Preeti and welcome to stackoverflow. Why do you use `SELECT ID FROM (SELECT * FROM table1)` instead of `SELECT ID FROM table1` ?

Comment: because, when i use "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table1) "  both table1 as a target for 'DELETE'  statement, and its throw an error. So avoiding to this I use "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM (SELECT * FROM table1) as tab". Now DELETE take table1 and tab as a two different data sets.

Comment: Did you tested you query @Preeti ? Try to execute `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM (SELECT * FROM table1) as tab GROUP BY PARTYID, PARTYTYPE HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)`: You select `id` but group by `PARTYID, PARTYTYPE`. It will throw an error any way that `Column 'tab.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: It is hard to have a discussion in stackoverflow poor system using poor plain short text without option for readable code and longer respond `:-( `. We cannot publish DDL+DML in this short comment unfortunately in order to have productive discuss

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE and DELETE cannot be performed in one query. Use 2 separate queries.

Query 1. Update table, alter 'A' to 'B' when 'B' not exists and to NULL otherwise.

```sql
UPDATE test t1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT t2. PARTYID, 1 B_EXISTS
            FROM test t2
            WHERE t2.PARTYTYPE = 'B' ) t3 USING (PARTYID)
SET t1.PARTYTYPE = CASE WHEN t3.B_EXISTS
                        THEN NULL
                        ELSE 'B' 
                        END
WHERE t1.PARTYID IN (1, 2, 3) -- specify needed PARTYID values
  AND t1.PARTYTYPE = 'A';
```

Query 2. Remove rows with NULLs.

```sql
DELETE 
FROM test
WHERE PARTYTYPE IS NULL;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f9b310806821c166da7c384640ecf89

Comment: (1) This will remove rows which has NULLs before the update, which is not part of the requirement. In first query you UPDATE values to NULL and in second you delete all with NULL including these who were NULL before. Instead you could use OUTPUT to get the rows which were UPDATED or do second task first. (2) You forgot the condition `ON` in the `LEFT JOIN`. Strange since you publish code in dbfiddle. I am wondering how did you executed the query

Comment: @RonenAriely *This will remove rows which has NULLs before the update* Correct. But if this column can store NULLs then any another value (which is impossible in this column by the logic but allowed by datatype) must be used instead. Also this won't work if the column is defined as NOT NULL. *You forgot the condition ON in the LEFT JOIN.* There are 3 forms of JOIN - with ON clause, with USING clause, and NATURAL. I use 2nd option.

Comment: Check my solution please @Akina , It cover the option of having NULL. Try your solution on the DML which I used (I added three more rows to cover more cases)

Comment: @RonenAriely Уour current solution also has some drawbacks. (1) OP marks the question as MySQL-related, and the solution is not applicable for MySQL with the version before 8. (2) OP have not claimed that (PARTYID, PARTYTYPE) is unique.

Comment: `(2) OP have not claimed that (PARTYID, PARTYTYPE) is unique.` : My solution cover unique and non-unique partyType as well. I even added data to the sample data to test this. Check that I added tows with id 7,8,9 to show that it cover some cases the OP did not described and I started the answer which explaining this `:-)` but the issue of having two different lanagues in the same question (fact that is hidden in tags only) is annoying and might lead to a good answer which the OP will not be able to use and see it as a wrong query :-(

Comment: I even added 4 more rows now in order to check duplicate rows `insert into tempTable VALUES(11,6, 'B'); insert into tempTable VALUES(12,6, 'B'); insert into tempTable VALUES(13,7, 'A'); insert into tempTable VALUES(14,7, 'A')` and my solution covers this perfect and reasult is as expected (in SQL Server obviously!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute 2 queries :

- the first one to update your lines with only partyType as A
- the second one to delete lines with A and B data

Here my example with a tempTable :

```
declare @tempTable TABLE 
(
    Id int ,
    PARTYID int,
    PARTYTYPE varchar(1)
)


insert into @tempTable VALUES(1,1,'A')
insert into @tempTable VALUES(2,1,'B')
insert into @tempTable VALUES(3,1,'C')
insert into @tempTable VALUES(4,2,'A')
insert into @tempTable VALUES(5,2,'B')
insert into @tempTable VALUES(6,3,'A')


select * from @tempTable

update @tempTable
set PARTYTYPE ='B'
where Id in 
(
    select t.id from @tempTable t
    left outer join @tempTable tB on tB.PARTYID = t.PARTYID and tB.PARTYTYPE !='A'
    where
         t.PARTYTYPE ='A'
        and tB.Id is null
)

select * from @tempTable

delete from @tempTable
where Id 
in
    (
    select t.id from @tempTable t
    inner join @tempTable tA on tA.PARTYID = t.PARTYID and tA.PARTYTYPE ='A'
    inner join @tempTable tB on tB.PARTYID = t.PARTYID and tB.PARTYTYPE ='B'
    where 
        t.PARTYTYPE ='A'
    )

select * from @tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following queries covers all you need including all optional cases.

Note! to cover some cases, which were not described, I add three more rows to the sample data which was provided. This present also a case of multiple rows with the same PARTYTYPE for the same PARTYID and a case that PARTYTYPE is NULL. please check it

### DDL+DML (sample table and data)

```
CREATE TABLE tempTable (
    Id int ,
    PARTYID int,
    PARTYTYPE varchar(1)
)

TRUNCATE TABLE tempTable
GO
insert into tempTable VALUES(1,1,'A')
insert into tempTable VALUES(2,1,'B')
insert into tempTable VALUES(3,1,'C')
insert into tempTable VALUES(4,2,'A')
insert into tempTable VALUES(5,2,'B')
insert into tempTable VALUES(6,3,'A')
insert into tempTable VALUES(7,1,'A')
insert into tempTable VALUES(8,4, NULL)
insert into tempTable VALUES(9,5, 'B')

select * from tempTable
GO
```

### First: UPDATE rows

> if PARTYID have only one PARTYTYPE as 'A' then i need to update it to 'B'

```
;WITH MyCTE as (
    SELECT Id, PARTYID,PARTYTYPE, 
        C = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PARTYID)
    FROM tempTable
)
UPDATE MyCTE
SET PARTYTYPE = 'B'
WHERE C = 1 and PARTYTYPE = 'A'
GO -- OK
select * from tempTable
GO
```

### Second DELETE rows

> if PARTYID have both PARTYTYPE 'A' and 'B' then i need to delete 'A'

```
;WITH MyCTE as (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.Id--, t1.PARTYID, t1.PARTYTYPE, t2.PARTYTYPE
    FROM tempTable t1
    LEFT JOIN tempTable t2 ON t1.PARTYID = t2.PARTYID
    WHERE t1.PARTYTYPE = 'A' and t2.PARTYTYPE = 'B'
)
DELETE tempTable
WHERE id in (select * from MyCTE)
GO
select * from tempTable
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

this request is very simple!

```
declare @PartyTable table (id int, partyid int, partytype varchar(1)); 
--> I declared a variable table because I don't know what you called your physical table and I didn't want to create the physical table in my db to test the code. 
--  In any case, the result does not change.

insert into @PartyTable (id,partyid,partytype)
values (1,1,'A'),(2,1,'B'),(3,1,'C'),(4,2,'A'),(5,2,'B'),(6,3,'A'); --> I inserted into table the values.

select * from @PartyTable order by id; --> Select of your table of example

--Query 1: if PARTYID have only one PARTYTYPE as 'A' then i need to update it to 'B'
update t set partytype = 'B'
from @PartyTable t
where not exists (select 1 from @PartyTable t1 where t1.partyid = t.partyid and t1.partytype != 'A' )
and t.partytype = 'A';

--> Query 2: if PARTYID have both PARTYTYPE 'A' and 'B' then i need to delete 'A'    
delete t
from @PartyTable t
where exists (select 1 from @PartyTable t2 where t2.partyid = t.partyid and t2.partytype != 'A' )
and t.partytype = 'A';

-- Final result:
select * from @PartyTable order by id;
```

I hope this code will help you.